# Could there exist a planar graph with the following degrees of vertices: {5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2}

Tags: discrete-mathematics, planar-graphs

I was wondering if a graph existed because I used euler's inequality and it said that theres supposed to be a graph but im having a hard time figuring out what it is. Thank you!

Comment: Connect two of the vertices to each other and to all the other vertices. Connect three of the other four vertices to each other. Done.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The graph needs to be planar.

Comment: Euler's inequality doesn't guarantee planarity, does it? So, it's irrelevant, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe, ploop, you could clarify which definition of *graph* you are using. Specifically, do you allow multiple edges? Do you allow loops?

Comment: Are you still here, ploop?

Comment: You recieved 3 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider accepting the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Up to graph isomorphism, there exists only one graph with those vertex degrees. If we call the vertices $v_1,\dots, v_6$ where degree of $v_1$ and $v_2$ is $5$, and the degree of $v_6$ is $2$, then we know:

1. $v_1$ and $v_2$ must be connected to **all** other vertices.
2. $v_6$ is connected to $v_1$ and $v_2$ because of (1), and can have no other connections because it has degree $2$.
3. Vertices $v_3,v_4$ and $v_5$ cannot be connected to $v_6$ (because of (2)), therefore, they are all connected to all other vertices.
4. Therefore, $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5\}$ is a **fully connected subgraph** of the original graph.

So, your graph is basically just $K_5$, with one more vertex connected to two of its nodes. And it's well known that $K_5$ is not planar.

Comment: ok thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of the required planar graph.[image: planar graph]

Comment: I imagine OP's intended definition of *graph* excludes multiple edges, but since OP did not make this provision explicit, your answer can't be denied.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a graph with the degrees you specified:

[image: Graph with lots of loops]

Comment: Probably not what OP had in mind when using the word *graph*, but maybe this will force OP to see the importance of making all conditions explicit.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I agree.